# Next.js React component getInitialProps doesn't bind props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In Next.js, you can use in your React components a lifecycle method bound to the server side rendering on first load.

I tried to use this function as presented in [the ZEIT tutorial](https://zeit.co/blog/next#data-fetching-is-up-to-the-developer) (alternatively [on their Github](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#component-lifecycle)), but this.props doesn't seem to get JSON returned by the function. 
When I click on the component, console print an empty object.

```
import React from 'react'
import 'isomorphic-fetch'
export default class extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps () {
        const res = await fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json')
        const data = await res.json()
        return { data }
    }
    print() {
        console.log(this.props);
    }
    render() {
        return <div onClick={this.print.bind(this)}>print props</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to get this in a /pages component. Otherwise getInitialProps is not called. Are you defining a page or a component?

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue due to a problem in my _app.js (i.e. [NextJS Custom App](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-%3Capp%3E)) which I caused while adding in Redux (not a Redux issue).  As soon as I started using getInitialProps in a page my props were empty at render though data was there in the static call.  The cause was the incorrect propagation of pageProps in my _app.js.

So in my case the fix was changing, in custom _app.js getInitialProps, this:

```
return {
  ...pageProps,
  initialReduxState: reduxStore.getState()
}
```

to:

```
return {
  pageProps: {...pageProps},
  initialReduxState: reduxStore.getState()
}
```

.. so the render method as seen in the NextJS doc link could wire them through.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. For me it was a life saver, I would have never solved that myself. I know this is already a year old, but if possible could you or someone else explain more in detail why this issue occurs and how the fix exactly works?

Answer (score 0):

you can make your call in getInitialProps method like this with little modification in your code

```
import React from 'react'
import 'isomorphic-fetch'
export default class extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps () {
        const res = await fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json')
        const data = await res.json()
        return { jsonData: data }
    }
    print() {
        console.log(this.props.jsonData);
    }
    render() {
        return <div onClick={()=> this.print()}>print props</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: I get `undefined` :( in the console and `Access to fetch at 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json' from origin 'http://localhost:7777' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: @ChanceSmith This have nothing to do with `react` or `nextjs`. It's about `cors` policy. You should google what is it so you can understand better

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code and it seems to work fine, console shows `this.props`:

[image: Result object]